# D3: Yet another "Cannot read property 'weight' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a force-directed graph with one twist: the node and link data comes from externally defined classes.    When I run it, I get the dreaded and familiar message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'weight' of undefined
```

I've read [d3: Cannot read property 'weight' of undefined in d3.force implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28558334/558639) and the excellent https://stackoverflow.com/a/15060978/558639.  But no joy.

I've created a JSFiddle in https://jsfiddle.net/3xcaqaLc/8/ which faithfully replicates the error.

#### what I've tried

The docs mentions a 'weights' property on the links, but it wasn't particularly clear if I needed to provide that.

I added a `weight: 1.0` property to each link.  No joy.

I added a `weight: 1.0` property to each node.  No joy.

#### what I've not tried

All the examples I found show the links constructed with zero-based indexes into the nodes array.  Instead, I'm constructing the links with references to the nodes themselves.  But according to the documentation for `#force.nodes()`, this should work (note the use of the word 'may'):

> Note: the values of the source and target attributes may be initially
>   specified as indexes into the nodes array; these will be replaced by
>   references after the call to start.

Perhaps the documents are inaccurate, but solutions will be welcome!

Comment: This is not about the *weight* property, but the object that you are trying to read the weight of. You need to make sure that the expression that references it is actually referencing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real reason is that the link `g_graph.links` is not in the correct format as mentioned in https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#links

Same follows with the nodes 
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#nodes

That is the reason why force layout is not working.

I have commented the nodes and link section and graph is drawn because tick function is placing the node and the link.

```
  var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([view_width, view_height])
    //.nodes(g_graph.nodes)
    //.links(g_graph.links)
    .start();
```

working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/rqu8e5L6/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh - that's WAY better than my solution.  (The docs make sense, but could be a bit clearer.)  You get the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

While @RobG was giving his helpful answer, I figured it out with the help of the Chrome debugger.  In retrospect, it's kind of obvious.

d3's `link` operations expect the link to have .source and .target properties, not ._lh and ._rh properties defined by my Link class.

The fix was to map ._lh and ._rh to .source and .target on initialization, essentially:

```
var my_links = links.map(function(lnk) {return {source:lnk._lh, target:lnk._rh}})
```

Updated (and working) jsfiddle in https://jsfiddle.net/3xcaqaLc/9/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and commenting `.node()` and `.links()` as in accepted answer led to empty graph. So I made two things:

1. Downgraded d3 version to http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js cause v.4 seems to be fully incompatible with all this stuff, no `scale`, `layout`, etc.
2. changed `start` and `end` props of my links to `source` and `target` respectively

That's it, no need to add `weight`