# Cannot read property 'weight' of undefined and Cannot read property 'x' of undefined d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, svg

I have created a fiddle here to replicate the issue: [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/km4co7tz/)

Prior to this we were using a nice flat json file in our project. The new file I have to work with is much more nested.

My d3 function looks like this:

```
/* chart data */
// return data for relationships between database tables
returnTableRelationshipData = function(){

    var url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/7ovnb.json';
    d3.json(url, function(data){

        //find the node index
        function find(f){
          var i = -1
            data.p.nodes.forEach(function(node, index){
                node.x = 200 + Math.random()*200;
                node.y = 150 + Math.random()*200;
                if(node.properties.nodeID.val == f)
                    i = index;
            });
            return i;
        }

        //set the source and target index
        data.p.relationships.forEach(function(d){
            d.start = find(d.start);
            d.end = find(d.end);
        });

        // used to store the number of links between two nodes. 
        var mLinkNum = {};

        // sort links first
        sortLinks();                                

        // set up linkIndex and linkNumer, because it may possible multiple links share the same source and target node
        setLinkIndexAndNum();

        // check that we don't have empty or null values
        checkDataNotEmpty();

        var w = 1000;
        var h = 400;

        var force = d3.layout.force()
            .nodes(data.p.nodes)
            .links(data.p.relationships)
            .alpha(.1)
            .gravity(1)
            .charge(-10000)
            .size([w, h])
            .start();

        var svg = d3.select('.node-wrapper').append('svg')
            .attr('width', w)
            .attr('height', h);

        var path = svg.append('svg:g')
            .selectAll('path')
            .data(force.links())
            .enter().append('line')
            .attr('class', 'link')
            .attr('x1', function(d) {
                return d.start.x;
            })
            .attr('y1', function(d) {
                return d.start.y;
            })
            .attr('x2', function(d) {
                return d.end.x;
            })
            .attr('y2', function(d) {
                return d.end.y;
            });

        var node_drag = d3.behavior.drag()
            .on('dragstart', dragstart)
            .on('drag', dragmove)
            .on('dragend', dragend);

        var circle = svg.append('svg:g')
            .selectAll('circle')
            .data(force.nodes())
            .enter().append('svg:circle')
            .attr('r', 6)
            .call(node_drag);

        var text = svg.append('svg:g')                                
            .selectAll('g')
            .data(force.nodes())
            .enter().append('svg:g');

        text.append('svg:text')
            .text(function(d){ 
                return d.description;
            });

        force.on('tick', tick);

        function tick() {
            path.attr('x1', function(d) {
                return d.start.x;
            })
            .attr('y1', function(d) {
                return d.start.y;
            })
            .attr('x2', function(d) {
                return d.end.x;
            })
            .attr('y2', function(d) {
                return d.end.y;
            });

            circle.attr('transform', function(d){
                return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
            });

            text.attr('transform', function(d){
                return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
            });
        }

        function dragstart(d, i) {
            force.stop(); // stops the force auto positioning before you start dragging
        }

        function dragmove(d, i) {
            d.px += d3.event.dx;
            d.py += d3.event.dy;
            d.x += d3.event.dx;
            d.y += d3.event.dy;
            tick();
        }

        function dragend(d, i) {
            d.fixed = true; // of course set the node to fixed so the force doesn't include the node in its auto positioning stuff
            tick();
        }

        // sort the links by source, then target
        function sortLinks(){
            if(data.p.relationships != null){                         
                data.p.relationships.sort(function(a,b){
                    if(a.start > b.start){
                        return 1;
                    }else if(a.start < b.start){
                        return -1;
                    }else{
                        if(a.end > b.end){
                            return 1;
                        }if(a.end < b.end){
                            return -1;
                        }else{
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        //any links with duplicate source and target get an incremented 'linknum'
        function setLinkIndexAndNum(){                              
            for(var i = 0; i < data.p.relationships.length; i++){
                if(i != 0 &&
                    data.p.relationships[i].start == data.p.relationships[i-1].start &&
                    data.p.relationships[i].end == data.p.relationships[i-1].end){
                    data.p.relationships[i].linkindex = data.p.relationships[i-1].linkindex + 1;
                }else{
                    data.p.relationships[i].linkindex = 1;
                }// save the total number of links between two nodes
                if(mLinkNum[data.p.relationships[i].end + ',' + data.p.relationships[i].start] !== undefined){
                    mLinkNum[data.p.relationships[i].end + ',' + data.p.relationships[i].start] = data.p.relationships[i].linkindex;
                }else{
                    mLinkNum[data.p.relationships[i].start + ',' + data.p.relationships[i].end] = data.p.relationships[i].linkindex;
                }
            }
        }

        function checkDataNotEmpty(){
            data.p.relationships.forEach(function(link, index, list) {
                if (typeof link.start === 'undefined') {
                    console.log('undefined link', data.p.nodes[link.start]);
                }
                if (typeof link.end === 'undefined') {
                    console.log('undefined source', data.p.nodes[link.end]);
                }
            });
        }

    });
}();
```

As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35906388/1238244) if I comment out these lines:

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
            //.nodes(data.p.nodes)
            //.links(data.p.relationships)
            .alpha(.1)
            .gravity(1)
            ...
```

Then an svg object is appended to the html.

The answer linked doesn't actually provide a solution to this.

Both nodes and links appear to be iterated over properly. 
[image: screenshot of nodes]

My only hunch is that somehow I have to map `"start"` and `"end"` to `source` and `target`, or I need to transform `data.p.nodes` and `data.p.relationships` somehow. Or maybe the indexing is not working correctly.

I am able to work with a backend developer to change some of the json properties and types (string, integer and so on).

The json file is being called from here: http://myjson.com/7ovnb

Comment: OK, my nodes are working, just not seeing the path connections. They are being rendered but not being passed the x1, x2, y1 etc params https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/km4co7tz/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define a stroke for the links to make them visible:

   ```
   .node-wrapper line {
     stroke: #0D9E1E;
   }
   ```
2. Rename all occurences of `.start` with `.source` and of `.end` with `.target` in the `tick()` function.
3. In your `find()` function, you have to compare to the `node.id` property:

   ```
   function find(f){
     var i; // do not return an existing value as default
       data.p.nodes.forEach(function(node, index){
           node.x = 200 + Math.random()*200;
           node.y = 150 + Math.random()*200;
           if(node.id == f)
               i = index;
       });
       return i;
   }
   ```

   Index 0 if is an existing node index, so it would be a better idea not to set it as default.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and implement it in the morning and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thank you very much @ccprog